# SQL - Building iteration table

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a problem with table's iteration. There is status product (`test_product`) in stock and actions: add or remove from stock.

| product | action | operation_date | number | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_product | add | 2023-01-03 | 4 | 4 |
| test_product | remove | 2023-01-05 | -3 | 1 |
| test_product | remove | 2023-01-07 | -1 | 0 |

In some day we have add or remove product, number of product and total number.

I want to count number of days, where total number is `0` in some period, let's say from **`2023-01-01`** to **`2023-01-10`** with starting value of `total` column is `0`.

In my mind I have table like this:

| calendar_day | product | action | operation_day | number | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-02 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-03 | test_product | add | 2023-01-03 | 4 | 4 |
| 2023-01-04 |  |  |  |  | 4 |
| 2023-01-05 | test_product | remove | 2023-01-05 | -3 | 1 |
| 2023-01-06 |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 2023-01-07 | test_product | remove | 2023-01-07 | -1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-08 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-09 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-10 |  |  |  |  | 0 |

Counting of `0` days is technical operation, it's not important now. Problem is building table.

I've tried something like this:

```
GO
DECLARE @PRODUCT AS VARCHAR(30)
SET @PRODUCT = 'test_product'
DECLARE @TOTAL AS INT
SET @TOTAL = 0
DECLARE @STOP_DATE AS DATE;
SET @STOP_DATE = CAST('2023-01-10' AS DATE)
DECLARE @UP_DATE AS DATE;
SET @UP_DATE = CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATE);
WHILE @STOP_DATE >= @UP_DATE
BEGIN  
SELECT
@UP_DATE AS calendar_day,
CASE
WHEN operation_date = @UP_DATE THEN operation_date
ELSE ''
END AS operation_date,
number,
@TOTAL+number AS total
FROM stock
JOIN products ON products.id = stock.product_id
WHERE products.name = @PRODUCT
AND stock.operation_date >= @UP_DATE
AND stock.operation_date <= @UP_DATE
SET @UP_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @UP_DATE)
END
```

But I've got separation result, 7 of them are empty and it's too slow, because we have 9000 items for now.

Can you help me?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: im using MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish to this task into three steps:

- build a calendar table with a recursive query, that stops at `calen_date < '2023-10-01'`
- left join the calendar table with your products table
- compute a running sum on your number value to get your total.

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATE) AS calendar_day
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, calendar_day) FROM calendar WHERE calendar_day < '2023-01-10'
)
SELECT calendar_day, product, action_, operation_date, number, 
       SUM(COALESCE(number,0)) OVER(ORDER BY calendar_day) AS total
FROM      calendar     c
LEFT JOIN test_product p
       ON c.calendar_day = p.operation_date
```

Output:

| calendar_day | product | action | operation_day | number | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-02 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-03 | test_product | add | 2023-01-03 | 4 | 4 |
| 2023-01-04 |  |  |  |  | 4 |
| 2023-01-05 | test_product | remove | 2023-01-05 | -3 | 1 |
| 2023-01-06 |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 2023-01-07 | test_product | remove | 2023-01-07 | -1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-08 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-09 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 2023-01-10 |  |  |  |  | 0 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MqZecoCs).

Comment: I've been a bit confused here
`SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, calendar_day) FROM calendar WHERE calendar_day < '2023-10-01'`
but I've understood that you didn't notice that you used month instead of day in date :)
however, thank's you a lot!

Comment: I realized about the month-day inversion, that's why I couldn't understand why I got all null values in first place, although I've switched them and assumed you were using standard dates.

Comment: `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, calendar_day) FROM calendar WHERE calendar_day < '2023-01-10'` fixed it

Comment: So you were going for days not months, I see it. Let me adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: ok, now I see perfect sql ;) thanks you again

Comment: And how can I get `total` amount? If I, for example, don't have that last column `total`?
My product has `0` for a start, then I add `4` and in `total` column will be `0+4=4` value for a couple days, then I remove `3` items and in `total` column I have `4-3=1` for couple days, than remove `1` items and `1-1=0`

Comment: The answer to this question can already be found in this answer, updated 23 minutes ago. It's simpler and works better. Does it match your needs?

Comment: oh, sure. I didn't see your amendments